# Running iOS simulator NOT in debug mode

Tags: xcode, flutter, debugging, ios-simulator, screenshot

I try to create screenshots for my iOS Flutter app using the iOS simmulator.
I need those screenshots to submit my app to the App Store.

The problem is, all the simulators (iPhone, iPad etc) show a prominent DEBUG sign on the top of the simulator screen (see the screenshot).

Is there a setting, either in xCode or Simulator app that allows to run the simulator in non-debug mode?
App store requires screenshots for several different types of devices, and I dont't have (or can afford) all of them.

[Debug mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVDbA.jpg)

I run xCode 14 on macOs Monterrey.

In a more general mode - how do people create screenshots for iOS without owning a bunch of physical Apple devices?

I looked for a way to run xCode in non-debug mode, with no success.
I also ran iOS simulator using "flutter run" command out of the console, but it still launches the iOS simulator in a debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CupertinoApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,)` or `MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,)`depending on which one you use.

also you need to run `flutter run --release` to run release build.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes

Comment: I tried flutter run --release. it doesn't work - I get the message that the simulator is not supported in the --release mode (same for --profile mode)

Comment: @skiffrace try running it from Xcode. I found that simply changing my main to MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,) was all I needed

Answer (score 0):

PurplePolyhedron - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I set the debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false and it did the trick.

Thanks again!